# Touchpad changes tap from click to hold, and right click menu freezes on screen, clears on restart

Tags: windows, touchpad, acer-aspire

I have the following issue:

After continued usage of a windows 10 based Acer laptop, the touchpad behavior changes to "tap to hold left click" from "tap to left click". Additionally, as this happens, the right click menu items tend to freeze on the screen after clicking (a graphics error). Everything clears after restarting.

Additionally, the touchpad always goes completely crazy, if a a draft is used on top of it. I suppose this is not related, but worth mentioning anyway.

Is there any way to remedy this error by restarting some processes perhaps?

Comment: Have you checked the "palm" sensitivity? I have seen strange behaviours on laptops when it thinks there is a hand resting on the touchpad.

Comment: @Andy Where is such setting located? I haven't seen it in the touchpad settings.

Comment: Usually you open the mouse settings and one of the tabs will have a button that opens an additional bit of software such as "ELAN" or "Symantec" control panel. This control panel usually has the extra option mentioned, as well as 2 finger scrolling etc.

Comment: @Andy I can't find such a setting... now that you mentioned, I think there may be something wrong with the driver that may be related.